# Construct Javascript Object from listener event

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have a listener event that's triggering with a parameter "data" that looks like this:

```
{field_id: 13, meta_value: 'a', rowid: 0}
{field_id: 13, meta_value: 'ab', rowid: 0}
{field_id: 13, meta_value: 'abc', rowid: 0}
{field_id: 14, meta_value: 'd', rowid: 0}
{field_id: 14, meta_value: 'de', rowid: 0}
{field_id: 14, meta_value: 'def', rowid: 0}
{field_id: 13, meta_value: 'b', rowid: 1}
{field_id: 13, meta_value: 'bb', rowid: 1}
{field_id: 13, meta_value: 'bbb', rowid: 1}
{field_id: 14, meta_value: 'c', rowid: 1}
{field_id: 14, meta_value: 'cc', rowid: 1}
{field_id: 14, meta_value: 'ccc', rowid: 1}
```

I would like to turn this into an object like

```
{
    0: {
        {
            field_id: 13,
            meta_value: abc
        },
        {
            field_id: 14,
            meta_value: def
        }
    },
    
    1: {
        {
            field_id: 13,
            meta_value: bbb
        },
        {
            field_id: 14,
            meta_value: ccc
        }
    }
}
```

I've tried simply:

```
outputValue[rowid][field_id] = data;
```

Unfortunately this approach creates an array with lots of empty indexes. Preferably I would like to construct an object where the keys are the rowid and {field_id, meta_value} are created or overwritten if an existing field_id can be matched like above.

Comment: What is preventing you from creating the desired object?

Comment: the object is not possible (your example), its shape is not of a valid JS object

Comment: I assume you want an array and you accidentally used `{`

Answer (score 0):

The described object

```
{
    0: {
        {
            field_id: 13,
            meta_value: abc
        },
        {
            field_id: 14,
            meta_value: def
        }
    },
    
    1: {
        {
            field_id: 13,
            meta_value: bbb
        },
        {
            field_id: 14,
            meta_value: ccc
        }
    }
}
```

is not valid.

I assume that you wanted an object more like this:

```
{
    0: {
        13: {
            meta_value: "abc"
        },
        14: {
            meta_value: "def"
        }
    },
    1: {
        13: {
            meta_value: "bbb"
        },
        14: {
            meta_value: "ccc"
        }
    }
}
```

Although the merging of `meta_value`s is not clear, I assume, you want the last to be stored.

It's relatively easy to construct a function that does this for you:

```js
const events = [{
  field_id: 13,
  meta_value: 'a',
  rowid: 0
}, {
  field_id: 13,
  meta_value: 'ab',
  rowid: 0
}, {
  field_id: 13,
  meta_value: 'abc',
  rowid: 0
}, {
  field_id: 14,
  meta_value: 'd',
  rowid: 0
}, {
  field_id: 14,
  meta_value: 'de',
  rowid: 0
}, {
  field_id: 14,
  meta_value: 'def',
  rowid: 0
}, {
  field_id: 13,
  meta_value: 'b',
  rowid: 1
}, {
  field_id: 13,
  meta_value: 'bb',
  rowid: 1
}, {
  field_id: 13,
  meta_value: 'bbb',
  rowid: 1
}, {
  field_id: 14,
  meta_value: 'c',
  rowid: 1
}, {
  field_id: 14,
  meta_value: 'cc',
  rowid: 1
}, {
  field_id: 14,
  meta_value: 'ccc',
  rowid: 1
}]


const state = () => {
  const _res = {}

  const setVal = (obj) => ({ field_id, meta_value, rowid }) => {
    if (typeof obj[rowid] === "undefined") obj[rowid] = {}
    obj[rowid][field_id] = { field_id, meta_value }

    return obj
  }
  const addToRes = setVal(_res)
  return {
    res,
    addToRes,
  }
}

const { res, addToRes } = state()


events.forEach(addToRes)
console.log(res)
```